# Crossing link and Matrix

Tags: cross-referencing, matrices

I try to establish a crossing link to check if all variables used are defined somewhere in the document. The goal is to identify impact when a variable is modify, and when a variable isn't defined. The final objectiv is to have more quality in a software specification.

For that, I store all variables in two arrays (one for used, one for definition) and at the end I evaluate if each variable in in the used array are present in the defined array.
The crossing link, distribution and security about not defined variables work well.
The problem is on the link in the "Matrix" table, all link to the same.

You can find the code below

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xinttools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}

\newcounter{Cpt}
\newcommand{\VARRRI}{}
\newcommand{\VARRRO}{}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\DefVariable}[1]{  \textbf{#1}  \phantomsection  \def\@currentlabel{#1}  \label{[var@#1]}  \g@addto@macro\VARRRI{{var@#1}} \global\@namedef{var@#1@ismetby}{} }

\newcommand{\meetsreqY}[1]{\@ifundefined{r@[var@#1]}{THIS VARIABLE ISN T DEFINED #1 !!}{{} \expandafter\g@addto@macro\csname var@#1@ismetby\expandafter\endcsname \expandafter {\expandafter{\@currentspece}}}}

\newcommand{\specswithreqY}[1] {\xintListWithSep{, }{\xintApply { \nameref}{\csname #1@ismetby\endcsname }}}

\newcommand{\specY}[1]{\label{va@#1}\xdef\@currentspece{va@#1}}

\newcommand{\UseVariable}[1]{\stepcounter{Cpt}\specY{\theCpt}\ref{[var@#1]}  \g@addto@macro\VARRRO{{#1} } }
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{section1}
\DefVariable{MeasureVoltage1} : Hardware input

\section{section2} 
\DefVariable{FaultOvervoltage} : \UseVariable{MeasureVoltage1} sup to 50

\section{section5}
\DefVariable{TotalVoltage} : \UseVariable{MeasureVoltage1} add with \UseVariable{MeasureVoltage2}

\section{section3}
\DefVariable{MeasureVoltage2} : I define this variable

\section{section4} 
\DefVariable{FaultOvervoltage} : \UseVariable{MeasureCurrent} sup to 50

\clearpage
\section{Tracability MAtrix}

\xintFor* #1 in \VARRRO\do {\meetsreqY{#1}}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
section where variable is defined & section where variable is used    \\ 
\hline
\xintFor* #1 in \VARRRI\do {  \ref{[#1]}&\specswithreqY{#1}\\\hline }

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE :) // Sorry, don't understand: why do you want to do this? Thanks

Comment: Thanks. It's for identify impact when a variable is modify, and when a variable isn't defined. The final goal is to have more quality in software specification.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please edit your question and put your goal into a prominent place? Makes it easier for the rest of us ;-)